# What is the exact unit in LibGDX if it says "private static final float WORLD_SIZE = 480"?

Tags: libgdx

In the code I see that the WORLD_SIZE variable was initialized with 480 
private static final float WORLD_SIZE = 480;

What exactly the 480 means, are they pixels, cm or meters?

Answer (score 1):

A unit by itself is just a unit. It doesn't represent anything until you know the context of what it is used for.

If for example the WORLD_SIZE is used with Box2D to represent the size of the world then it is likely to be meters as Box2D works in meters.

If WORLD_SIZE is used to define the width/height of a world map texture then the units would be pixels.